# Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

VF Contrller::
public class ComponentHandler {
public id DispatchId{get;set;}
public list orders;
public listvarStr;
public list ordItms;
public listcaseIds;
public list casess;
public List ordId;
public ComponentHandler(){
list<Dispatch__c> prtcaseId=[select Case__c,id from Dispatch__c where id=:DispatchId];
for(Dispatch__c obj1:prtcaseId){
caseIds.add(obj1.Case__c);
}
if(caseIds.size()>0){
casess=[select id,Order__c from Case where case.Id=:caseIds];
}
if(casess.size()>0){
for(case obj2:casess){
ordId.add(obj2.Order__c);
}
}
if(ordId.size()>0){
orders=[select VAR_PO__c,name,(select id,Product2Id,Quantity,UnitPrice,Description from orderitems)
from order where order.id =:ordId ];
}
}
public list getvarPoList(){
if(ordId.size()>0){
varStr=[select VAR_PO__c,id from order where order.id =:ordId];
}
return varStr;

```
}
public list<orderItem> getorderItem(){
    for(order obj:orders){
        ordItms.addAll(obj.orderitems); 
    }
    return ordItms;

}
```

}

vf components::

```html
<apex:component controller="ComponentHandler" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="DispId" type="Id" description="Id of account" assignTo="{!DispatchId}"/>
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!orderItem}" var="ord">
            <apex:column title="Product" rendered="{!ord.Product2Id !=null}" value="{! If(ord.Product2Id !=null ,ord.Product2Id ,'') }"/>
            <apex:column title="Quantity"  rendered="{!ord.Quantity !=null}" value="{! If(ord.Quantity !=null ,ord.Quantity ,'') }"/>
            <apex:column title="Unit Price" rendered="{!ord.UnitPrice !=null}" value="{! If(ord.UnitPrice !=null ,ord.UnitPrice ,'') }"/>
            <apex:column title="Description" rendered="{!ord.Description !=null}" value="{! If(ord.Description !=null ,ord.Description ,'') }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!varPoList}" var="vap">
            <apex:column title="Var PO" rendered="{!vap.VAR_PO__c !=null}" value="{! If(vap.VAR_PO__c !=null ,vap.VAR_PO__c ,'') }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:component>
```

relation :: Dispatch__c is child of case and case is child of order.

Comment: The lists that you defined are not initialized. You can initialize them in the constructor first and then add or remove data.

Comment: @manjit5190 still i am getting the same error